# Creating a Framework-dependent executable

Tags: c#, msbuild

Following this question, I thought I had the answer on how to publish a dot net core console app so that it contained a *.exe files plus any *.dll relevant to nuget packages used.

Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#framework-dependent-executable) the following is what I think is meant work.

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained false -r win10-x64
```

So, this works in that I get a publish package with *.dlls for the libraries referenced as nuget packages. However, I still don't get a *.exe file.

Any suggestions as to where I might be going wrong on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looks like the ability to do this is dependent on the version of .NET Core being used.

See this answer from the .NET Core team: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/11439#issuecomment-497069989

I updated my .NET Core version and it works perfectly now.